# maprsteam with spring integration java client

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, spring-integration, mapr

I am looking for a solution to use **maprstream** with spring integration. I could able to create the stream and topic and also could able to consume/publish messages using stream:topic combination. Used the Kafka client by referring the [link](https://mapr.com/blog/getting-started-sample-programs-mapr-streams/):

But struggling to consume/publish message using Spring integration and couldn't see any sample programs explaining the same. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring-integration-kafka 2.0 (via spring-kafka 1.0) uses the 0.9 Kafka API.

See [the compatibility matrix at the bottom of the project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/).

It's not been tested with MapR.

Comment: In addition you should be sure that you really exclude `kafka-clients` dependency and include exactly that for the `0.9.0.0-mapr-1602` version.

Comment: Thanks Gary and Artem. The below versions worked for me.                                       spring-integration-kafka.version => 2.0.0 , spring-kafka.version => 1.0.0