# reprocess maprstream messages using spring integration kafka

Tags: spring-integration, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, mapr-streams

This is related to the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943870/maprsteam-with-spring-integration-java-client) and I am using spring-integration-kafka 2.0 to consume the messages from mapr stream topics.
I am facing difficulties to use the [KafkaConsumer](https://maprdocs.mapr.com/apidocs/60/mapr-streams-kafka/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) feature - *reprocess maprstream messages* - using offset and topic partitions.

If I can integrate seek feature I will be able to reprocess the messages based on offset value.

Can someone please help me to integrate the KafkaConsumer features [**seek**, **seekToBegining**, **seekToEnd**](https://maprdocs.mapr.com/apidocs/60/mapr-streams-kafka/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek(org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition,%20long)) in spring integration Kafka? The current consumer configuration is mentioned below:

```
 <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaListener"
    listener-container="container1"
    auto-startup="true"
    phase="100"
    send-timeout="5000"
    channel="inputFromStream"
    error-channel="errorChannel" />

<bean id="container1" class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092"/>
                <entry key="group.id" value="siTestGroup1"/>
                <entry key="enable.auto.commit" value="true"/>
                <entry key="auto.commit.interval.ms" value="1000"/>
                <entry key="auto.offset.reset" value="earliest" /> 
                <entry key="max.partition.fetch.bytes" value="3145728"/>
                <entry key="key.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"/>
                <entry key="value.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"/> 
            </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties">
            <constructor-arg name="topics" value="${maprstream.topicname}" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` - this is how Spring Cloud Stream does it...

```
final AtomicBoolean initialAssignment = new AtomicBoolean(true);
if (!"earliest".equals(resetTo) && "!latest".equals(resetTo)) {
    logger.warn("no (or unknown) " + ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG +
            " property cannot reset");
    resetOffsets = false;
}
if (groupManagement && resetOffsets) {
    containerProperties.setConsumerRebalanceListener(new ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevokedBeforeCommit(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> tps) {
            // no op
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsRevokedAfterCommit(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> tps) {
            // no op
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> tps) {
            if (initialAssignment.getAndSet(false)) {
                if ("earliest".equals(resetTo)) {
                    consumer.seekToBeginning(tps);
                }
                else if ("latest".equals(resetTo)) {
                    consumer.seekToEnd(tps);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
else if (resetOffsets) {
    Arrays.stream(containerProperties.getTopicPartitions())
            .map(tpio -> new TopicPartitionInitialOffset(tpio.topic(), tpio.partition(),
                    // SK GH-599     "earliest".equals(resetTo) ? SeekPosition.BEGINNING : SeekPosition.END))
                    "earliest".equals(resetTo) ? 0L : Long.MAX_VALUE))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(containerProperties.getTopicPartitions());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Gary, But I am using the below Jar combinations: Spring for Apache Kafka 1.0.3, Spring Integration for Apache Kafka 2.0.1, kafka-clients 0.9.0.0-mapr-1607   as per post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943870/maprsteam-with-spring-integration-java-client
and it looks like this versions doesn't supports ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener.

Comment: Correct; [it was added in an early milestone for 2.0.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/0d54a6bd1bf0cfb94c86f452ceec56f54d95c90e) - you can see which versions it is available in by clicking the `...` next to the tag icon. You are out of luck until the mapr folks upgrade to a more recent client. 0.9.x.x is ancient in the Kafka world.